# Browser mis-interpreting '&not' in URL

Tags: html, browser, html-parsing

Apparently if a URL containing the text `&not` is used as part of a field property, many browsers will interpret this as ['¬'](http://webref.info/?ID=12071).  So this HTML code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com?some_param=1&notify=true';">Click here</a>
```

will be rendered as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com?some_param=1¬ify=true';">Click here</a>
```

I found a couple of alternatives by substituting `&not` with `&%6Eot`, or by POSTing a form instead of GETting a parameterized URL.  But POSTs aren't always a welcome alternative and substitution is admittedly a hack - it will also need to deal with other common tokens as `&cent`, `&curren`, `&pound`, `&sect`, `&copy`, `&reg`...  (list taken from [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/paypal-ipn-problem-not-and-current)).

Surely someone out there has a better solution for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Element attributes are interpreted by the HTML parser, so you must escape `&` characters as `&amp;`. It works most of the time even if you don't, but in some cases (such as yours) you have to do it "right" or it won't work.