# preg_replace replacing &not in string to funny character

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-entities

For some reason when `preg_replace` sees `&not` in string and replaces it with `¬`:

```
$url= "http://something?blah=2&you=3&rate=22&nothing=1";

echo preg_replace("/&rate=[0-9]*/", "", $url) . "<br/>";
```

But the output is as follows:

```
http://something?blah=2&you=3¬hing=1      // Current result
http://something?blah=2&you=3&nothing=1   // Expected result
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: works as expected : https://eval.in/134317

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser mis-interpreting '&not' in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761418/browser-mis-interpreting-not-in-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` has special meaning when used URIs. Your URI contains  `&not`, which is a valid HTML entity on its own. It's being converted to `¬`, hence causing the trouble. Escape them properly as `&amp;not` to avoid this problem. If your data is fetched from elsewhere, you can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to do this automatically.

Comment: Double quotes have nothing to do with HTML entities.

Comment: echo preg_replace("/&amp;rate=[0-9]*/", "", htmlspecialchars ($url4))."<br/>";

Comment: By the way of your answer, what about the the first '&' character..? It displays as it like ..why ..?

Comment: @Elavarasan: Because that occurrence of `&` and the characters that follow has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `&amp`; in place of this `&`

because your `&no`  has special meaning

use this url :

```
http://something?blah=2&amp;you=3&amp;rate=22&amp;nothing=1
```

and then do your replace accordingly

Comment: Trouble is the data I am relying on is from elsewhere so I cannot specify &amp instead of &

Comment: ohh thats sad to hear, then better use regex to convert those `&` into `&amp;`first :P